# Discord.py Cooldown

Tags: discord.py

I made a discord economy bot. I want to include a loan function, where the user can ask for a loan. There would be a command cooldown. However, if they don't pay after the command cooldown has ended, the bot should automatically take the money.

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60*60*24*7, commands.BucketType.user)
async def loan(ctx, amount : int):

    loan_available = int(client.get_user_bal(Devada, testbot)['cash'])

    if int(amount) <= loan_available:

      time.sleep(1)

      await ctx.channel.send('You have been given ' + ''.join(str(amount) + ". You will have to pay " + str((int(amount)+int(amount)*0.1)) +" baguttes within 2 weeks."))

      client.change_user_bal(str(ctx.guild.id), str(ctx.author.id), cash=0, bank=amount, reason='loan')
      client.change_user_bal(str(ctx.guild.id), testbot, cash=-amount, bank=0, reason='loan')

      must_pay.update({ctx.author.name:str(amount)})

    else:

        time.sleep(2)

        await ctx.channel.send("You Can only request a loan within "+str(loan_available))
```

Is there any way to detect when the cooldown is over?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@commands.cooldown` attribute is used to add a cooldown to a command, so users can't spam that same command. Instead, they need to wait for a certain amount of time ( `60*60*24*7` seconds, in this case ) before being able to re-use the command.

However, if you want the bot to wait for `604800` seconds and then take the money back, you should use the `asyncio` module to wait for that amount of time without disturbing or stopping the other commands of the program. Here is how you can re-adjust your code:

```
import asyncio

@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60*60*24*7, commands.BucketType.user)
async def loan(ctx, amount : int):

    loan_available = int(client.get_user_bal(Devada, testbot)['cash'])

    if int(amount) <= loan_available:

      time.sleep(1)

      await ctx.channel.send('You have been given ' + ''.join(str(amount) + ". You will have to pay " + str((int(amount)+int(amount)*0.1)) +" baguttes within 2 weeks."))

      client.change_user_bal(str(ctx.guild.id), str(ctx.author.id), cash=0, bank=amount, reason='loan')
      client.change_user_bal(str(ctx.guild.id), testbot, cash=-amount, bank=0, reason='loan')

      must_pay.update({ctx.author.name:str(amount)})

    else:

        time.sleep(2)

        await ctx.channel.send("You Can only request a loan within "+str(loan_available))

    # New asyncio code
    
    await asyncio.sleep(60*60*24*7) # Wait for 60*60*24*7 seconds

    # Here, just add the code to take the money away after 60*60*24*7 seconds
```

**Note that if you restart your bot between the time, the bot won't execute the code after
`60*60*24*7` seconds. So you must keep the bot online without restarting it.**

Comment: Thanks, however, I have 1 question. When the function is waiting, can someone else ask for a loan?

Comment: Yes. Asyncio module doesn't affect the other commands and the command itself with delay. That's why it is advised to use asyncio to deal with time in d.py ;)

Answer (score 0):

The correct way of checking if a command's cooldown has finished is either checking if [`Command.is_on_cooldown`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=is_on_cooldown#discord.ext.commands.Command.is_on_cooldown) is false or even checking the time left on the command by using [`Command.get_cooldown_retry_after`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=get_cooldown_retry_after#discord.ext.commands.Command.get_cooldown_retry_after). You would need to check this every certain amount of time, so you could create a [Task](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html) that would call any of those functions and then evaluate the result to do whatever you want.